# YAD - Terminate Bash Script

Tags: shell-script, exit

I'm using [YAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/) to create a Yes or No dialog box in a bash script:

```
yad --image "dialog-question" --title "Alert" --button=gtk-yes:0 --button=gtk-no:1 --text "Are you sure you want to do this?"
```

If I click "No" to the question I want the bash script to terminate. If I click "Yes" I want the rest of the operations in the bash script to execute.

What code should I add to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a full working example :

```
if yad \
    --image "dialog-question" \
    --title "Alert" \
    --button=gtk-yes:0 \
    --button=gtk-no:1 \
    --text "Are you sure you want to do this?"
then
    do_the_rest...
    ...
    ...
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Do I replace "do the rest" with the others commands I want to execute were I to click "Yes"?

Comment: Duh, sure user8547 !

Comment: I tested it and it worked.

Comment: Are you surprised ? =)

Comment: I'm too busy being sexy to be surprised.